# VBA Macro Iteration

Tags: excel, vba

I need to repeat the following simple macro in every sheet; actually, the code performs the macro in the same sheet. How can I fix the code?

Thank you very much

```
Sub Macro1()
'


' Macro1 Macro
'

Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        With ws
            Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1"
            Cells.Select
            Selection.UnMerge
            Columns("D:D").Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            Columns("E:E").Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            Application.Goto Reference:="R10C9"
            Range("J10").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            Selection.EntireColumn.Delete
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this code in the workbook containing the worksheets being processed? After you have run this macro, should there be any data below row 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a bit of touch if that is what you really want to do:

```
Sub macro1()
' Macro1 Macro
'

Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        With ws
            .Activate
            .Range("A1").Select
            .Cells.Select
            .Application.Selection.UnMerge
            .Columns("D:D").Select
            .Application.Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            .Columns("E:E").Select
            .Application.Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            .Application.Goto Reference:="R10C9"
            .Range("J10").Select
            .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
            .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            .Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Delete
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```